# How to install bc2cnf in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, c++, ubuntu-20.04

I would like to use the bc2cnf tool to generate CNF for a digital circuit.
Please let me know how to install and run the [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/) tool (from the BC package) in ubuntu using the terminal.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have much experience compiling things I assume... So a very TERSE step-by-step:

1. Download the zip file, decompress it.
2. Open a shell and `cd` into the folder with the files.
3. `ls -l *.txt` reveals that there is a README file...
4. Type `less README.txt` (press ENTER as always!) to read it...
5. In there you find `make utilty_name` stated,
6. ... try exactly those at the shell prompt...
7. assuming there is no `error` or `failed` text printed as the processing (compile!) is done, you're likely to find that an executable named in the same manner has appeared,
8. check with `ls -l`.
9. `./utilty_name --help` may then give more hints on how to use it.

*Now note: I have NOT tried the above with the files you can download. So the above MAY fail, and I cannot help you with any problems there... That would require at least some knowledge about how these utilities are meant to work.*

Comment: I have followed the above steps and I am able to run the tool.
Thank you for providing step-by-step instructions.